# Typewriter effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I run this code I get nothing but just background color on screen.
typed.js is downloaded and placed in same folder. What's going wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>type js</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #bf1f26;
    }
    .type{
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script>

  <script src="typed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".type").typed({
            strings: [
            "Hello",
            "My Name Is Aditya Aundhekar",
            "I'm a Computer Engineer..",
            ],
        })
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <span class="type"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).typed is not a function TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function at HTMLDocument. (localhost/resume/typed.html:23:14) at mightThrow (code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js:3583:29) at process (code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js:3651:12) undefined jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.js:3860 jquery-3.2.1.js:3869 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function at HTMLDocument. (typed.html:23) at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583) at process (jquery-3.2.1.js:3651)

Comment: Do you get any errors in the developer console? Also, this doesn't make sense `src="typed js/lib/typed.min.js"` You have a space in there, plus you said _"typed.js is downloaded and placed in same folder"_

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Plus you didn't answer my question.

Comment: Press F12 on your browser and click on the console tab

Comment: I'm a little confused about which library you're using. I had a [similar error](https://jsfiddle.net/s4tfqLce/1/) when trying to use [Matt Boldt's library](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js) from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/typed.js). But [I had success](https://jsfiddle.net/s4tfqLce/) when using code from [a different test](https://codepen.io/lowercase/pen/BCJsf) which references [this library](https://codepen.io/lowercase/pen/rFHJs).

Comment: @showdev I have used Matt Boldt's library from his website.

Comment: Ok, I don't think that's a jQuery-based library. Did you see the setup example on [mattbodt.com](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/)?

Comment: @showdev yes, and i followed their steps and still getting this error..would you tell me how did you use the library from codepen.io?

Comment: I don't see code like yours in the examples: `$(".type").typed({`. The examples do not reference jQuery: `new Typed(".element", options);`. I think that's why you're getting an error from jQuery.

Comment: I can [understand the confusion](http://docs.minionmade.com/developer-tools/typedjs); not sure if something changed with that library... There's a similar one called [TypeIt](https://macarthur.me/typeit/) if you want to use jQuery.

Comment: @showdev i will try that one. thanks for your help man!

Comment: Maybe you are using version 2 of typed.js with the setup code from version 1? Looks like the library [was rewritten](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/releases) and is no longer a jQuery plugin. Also see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/issues/203).

Answer (score 2):

YOu are using wrong syntax,try this code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>type js</title>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: #bf1f26;
    }
    .type{
        color: black;
    }
</style>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script>

  <script src="typed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      var options = {
        strings: [
        "Hello",
        "My Name Is Aditya Aundhekar",
        "I'm a Computer Engineer.."]
    }

       var typed = new Typed(".type", options);
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <span class="type"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please *explain* what the solution you're showing does, and *why/how* that code answers the question.

Comment: @PriME they might downvote you, but this code worked for me perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, but the answer will be more useful when it explains how the solution solves a particular problem, rather than just providing inexplicably working code.

Comment: because he using a new version of typed js and old syntax :)

Comment: @adityaaundhekar if this answers your question mark this as right answer

Comment: I see, yeah. The [list of releases on GitHub](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/releases) show that version 1.1.5 was "jQuery free" and version 2.0 was "All new... written in ES6". That seems like the crux of the OP's issue. It seems like it would help keep track of things if the files included version numbers in their comments...

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your jQuery plugin is not loading before the typed.js. As it works fine otherwise you should see if `

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://pastebin.com/raw/RqHC6rCj" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <span class="type"></span>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".type").typed({
            strings: [
            "Hello",
            "My Name Is Aditya Aundhekar",
            "I'm a Computer Engineer..",
            ],
        })
    })
 
 </script>
</body>
```

`

Just see the snippet where I uploaded the JS plugin which is working fine.

So it is must that dependecy should be loaded first. So there is some loading issue.

I will remove the plugin by tomorrow from here so please let it check first. This is uploaded because I was not able to add it via references.

Edit: I have inserted the typed.js via link instead of including the whole plugin in the snippet and removed the typed.js plugin raw file from the snippet. Available for next 1 month then removed.

Comment: Where did you find that version of the typed.js library? Do you happen do know what version it is? Looks like it's pre-version-2.

Comment: I am using the same on my website. I don't know but it might be stored on my pc so I can check from there.. But I have downloaded it about 2-3 months ago.